# Vimeo thumbnails

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, vimeo

I use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to show Vimeo videoes on a site I am creating for a client - The client pastes the vimeo ID (the last letters in the url) in a field, and the video is shown. But I would also like to show thumbnail of the video, I am using the following (not working code) for this:

```
<?php
$imgid = the_field('video_link');
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$imgid.php"));
echo $hash[0]['thumbnail_medium'];  
?>
```

This code only shows the video-ID on the page. But if I, instead for "the_field('video_link')" writes the video-ID in the code - the thumbnail URL *is* displayed. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? :)

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with WordPress. Migrating to Stack Overflow where it will be more on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help

```
$videoID = the_field('video_link');
$jsonurl = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$videoID.'.json';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json,true);
echo '<img src="'. $json_output[0]['thumbnail_large'] .'" />';
```

It's the same call using json method

Comment: Thanks @ifdion
But I figures out I just needed to use get_field, instead of the_field! :)