# Vimeo thumbnails

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, vimeo

I use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to show Vimeo videoes on a site I am creating for a client - The client pastes the vimeo ID (the last letters in the url) in a field, and the video is shown. But I would also like to show thumbnail of the video, I am using the following (not working code) for this:

```
<?php
$imgid = the_field('video_link');
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$imgid.php"));
echo $hash[0]['thumbnail_medium'];  
?>
```

This code only shows the video-ID on the page. But if I, instead for "the_field('video_link')" writes the video-ID in the code - the thumbnail URL *is* displayed. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? :)

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with WordPress. Migrating to Stack Overflow where it will be more on-topic.

Comment: @EAMann I just flagged it to port it back to WPSE. This is about the WP Http API and belongs to us.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is a vanilla PHP function ... this is using a regular document from a third-party API. The question has absolutely *nothing* to do with WordPress or the `WP_Http` API.

Comment: Dupe that was closed: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61163/vimeo-thumbnails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help

```
$videoID = the_field('video_link');
$jsonurl = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$videoID.'.json';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json,true);
echo '<img src="'. $json_output[0]['thumbnail_large'] .'" />';
```

It's the same call using json method

Answer (score 0):

```
//vimeo thumb generator PHP
function getVimeoImg($id, $size = 'thumbnail_large'){
   if(get_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id)){
      $thumb_image = get_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id);
   }else{
      $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" . $id . ".json" ) );
      $thumb_image = $json[0]->$size;
      set_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id, $thumb_image, 2629743);
  }
  return $thumb_image;
}
```

add this to `functions.php`

than call thumbnail `echo getVimeoImg('videoID');`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Vimeo thumbnail via ID I setup a small application that let’s you do it like so:

```
https://vimg.now.sh/358629078.jpg
```